# How to retrieve application posts from 2.2 Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having trouble setting up my Android app to correctly query FB for specific application posts.

When I query `v2.2/page-id/feed` of course I get an array of posts where some of them contain filled up `application` structure like below:

```
"application": {
        "name": "HTC Sense",
        "id": "41158896424"
        }
```

How am I supposed to formulate query to `/feed` so I will only get posts that have specific `application->name/id` (were originally posted by specific application)?

**Edit:**
When i query `me/home?filter=app_124024574287414` (instagram app id) it works correctly, but when i query `page-id/feed?filter=app_124024574287414` the results are not filtered.

Is Graph API v2.2 really missing such important thing as filter (FQL had it), and the only way to achieve what i've described is local filtering (querying for all posts and present only some of them to user)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing what i'm trying to do seems to be impossible currently.